# Search for latest record using search by id and search by object

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I just got started with mongodb.

I am inserting into db like this:

```
def saveEntity(self, post):
    post_json = json.dumps(post)
    post_json_c = post_json.replace("\"", "'")
    cnt = self.collection.find().count()
    return {'oid': self.collection.insert(post), 'count': cnt }

record = {"author":"Ramesh"}
save_obj = obj.saveEntity(record)
```

Now suppose status of database is like this:

```
{u'_id': ObjectId('54e49c6f9f937b23296204cc'), u'author': u'Sanjeev'}
{u'_id': ObjectId('54e49d749f937b236a8405c4'), u'author': u'Sanjeev'}
{u'_id': ObjectId('54e49df59f937b2386d7c58e'), u'author': u'Sanjeev'}
{u'_id': ObjectId('54e49e299f937b239a9e314d'), u'author': u'Sanjeev'}
{u'_id': ObjectId('54e49e3d9f937b23a13a8ff8'), u'author': u'Sanjeev'}
{u'_id': ObjectId('54e5b6939f937b0f1a1f07ed'), u'author': u'Sanjeev'}
{u'_id': ObjectId('54e5bd059f937b152ffd0e58'), u'author': u'Menon'}
{u'_id': ObjectId('54e5bd0d9f937b15355d7e72'), u'author': u'Menon'}
{u'_id': ObjectId('54e5bd1d9f937b153f751e4d'), u'author': u'Nitin'}
{u'_id': ObjectId('54e5bd1f9f937b153f751e4e'), u'author': u'Nitin'}
{u'_id': ObjectId('54e5bd209f937b153f751e4f'), u'author': u'Nitin'}
{u'_id': ObjectId('54e5bd329f937b1549022d34'), u'author': u'Ramesh'}
{u'_id': ObjectId('54e5bd349f937b1549022d35'), u'author': u'Ramesh'}
```

While doing search, I did,

```
def getEntityBySearch(self, search):
    collect = self.collection.find(search)
    return collect

record = {"author":"Sanjeev"}      
fetchedData = obj.getEntityBySearch(record);    
for data in fetchedData:
    print data
```

result:

```
Fetched entity : 
{u'_id': ObjectId('54e5bd459f937b1549022d36'), u'author': u'Sanjeev'}
```

again

```
Fetched entity : 
{u'_id': ObjectId('54e5bd5d9f937b1549022d37'), u'author': u'Sanjeev'}
```

Dont know this is best way to do search or not.

Now what I want to do is:

1. Get entity by ID
2. Get entity by Object
3. Get latest entity. (like for Sanjeev there are multiple records, when I do search, dont know which record is coming, so I want most recent insert record for Sanjeev )

Help and suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You can try following options:

# Get Entity by ID/Object

from bson.objectid import ObjectID

def getEntityByID(self, id):
    obj_id = ObjectID(str(id))
    collect = self.collection.find({'_id':obj_id})
    return collect

# Get latest entity
def getLatestEntity(self, search_json, sort_by='_id'):
    collect = self.collection.find(search_json).sort([(sort_by, -1)]).limit(1)
    return collect
```

Comment: thanks, but I am getting `NameError: global name 'sort_by' is not defined` for `collect = self.collection.find(record).sort([(sort_by, -1)]).limit(1)` where record is input json

Comment: What did you pass as search_json? You may also consider replacing .sort([(sort_by, -1)]) with .sort({sort_by:-1}).